# Xamarin.Android SetContentView throws error

Tags: android, xamarin, android-appcompat

I'm working on an Android app that is supposed to run on android from 2.1 till the latest (4.4 right now). Everything worked fine until now, since the app decided to stop running on my Android 2.2 device. In the attached image is everything I think you're supposed to know to be able to help me.
I really don't know what is causing this, since the app runs fine on my Android 4.3.1 device.
The error I get is this:
"Binary XML file line #25: Error inflating class android.support.v7.internal.widget.ActionBarView"

It gives the error at SetContentView(Resources.Layout.Main);, which worked fine until now.
I've removed the main.axml file and readded it, but nothing changed, what should I change?
This is the main.axml file code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:padding="12dp">
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@android:id/content"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/content_frame"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
    </FrameLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

[image: Image overview of error]

Comment: Try to add reference to Mono.Android.Support.v7

Comment: Where do I find this? I'm using VS2013, and the Reference Manager only show Mono.Android.Support.V4 (and a whole lot of other ones of course), but not V7.

Comment: Update your xamarin, it should appear then

Comment: Thanks, updating Xamarin did the trick, I did not have to add it to the references, so I don't really know what caused it. But thanks, I got it working!